# YUI - 2 buttons open the pop up , how not to reset dialog values

Tags: yui, jquery-ui-datepicker

i am using YUI calendar .
I have two buttons which open the dialog 
 every time the calendar dialog gets opened , it's values are cleared , i want to get the last selected value

e.g 
2 buttons one for from date and one for to date 
scenario 
entering in "from" input calendar 01.01.2020
I would like the "to" button to open calendar with the date  01.01.2020 
and not today.

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle link, so we can see what is happening?

Comment: i am using wicket bnplug in so i need to insert using wicket the calander , and lots of stuff which are not visible to see happens from wicket , what i need is somthing like onOKDontReset varible.

Answer (score 0):

First create a calendar :

```
var cal = new YAHOO.widget.Calendar("DivContainerID");
cal.render();
```

then set the selected date on the click of the first button

```
cal.cfg.setProperty("selected","05/12/2014");
```